# Linear time multiplication on RAM machine?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, integers, multiplication

[This](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Garden#integer_multiplication) page says following:

> Integer Multiplication has an O-optimal linear-time algorithm on a RAM or SMM

Is this page fooling me or how can we multiply 2 numbers in linear time (bitwise complexity) using RAM?

Comment: Why do you think the page is talking about bit complexity?

Comment: Because when speaking of words it takes $O(1)$ time.

Answer (score 2):

The page is not fooling you. I'll refer you to the original paper, but accordingly they show the following:

> *Theorem 6.1* There exists an SMM which performs integer-multiplication in linear time, i.e. there is a constant $c$ such that any $2N$-bit input is read as the concatenation of two $N$-bit integers $x$, $y$, and after at most $cN$ many steps their product $z=xy$ is output in binary representation.

It is a rather detailed paper which would be silly to write up all here. See below.

Schönhage, A. (1980). Storage Modification Machines. *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 9(3), 490-508. https://doi.org/10.1137/0209036